# Special characters in JSON payload

Tags: wso2-esb

I have a requirement to have a json payload with special characters. I have a property set with special characters. If I use arg evaluator as 'json' and expression as '$.currentUserName', it comes as some junk characters instead of expected special characters. Here the special characters belong to one of the regional language. Please guide me. I am using WSO2 EI 6.1.1.

Comment: Does the regional language part of UTF-8? Can you provide sample request and response and what exactly is expected

Comment: yes, it is part of UTF-8. I am getting this from REST API response in JSON  format as below:

Comment: yes, it is part of UTF-8. I am getting this from REST API response in JSON  format as below: {  "currentUserName": "मनोजीत - बोस" }. I am able to extract this and store in a property called 'currentUserName'. I need to send this in JSON request payload to another API . For this, payload format is as follows: { "CURRENTUSERNAME": "$1" } with args as <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.currentUserName"/>. When I try to print the payload, I am getting some junk characters like "à¤ªà¥?à¤°à¤•à¤²à¥?à¤ª à¤µà¤¿à¤­à¤¾à¤".